# Warning : You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I need to separate my data collection according to **year**. Therefore the results will be displayed as follows:
[image]
If the results only display a collection of single year those will be displayed as:
[image]

When the results display a collection of single year, the filtration works fine. But when it comes to a few numbers of years, it doesn't work at all.

I think it's because of the below error:

> [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render
>   function.

My **`vue component`**:

```
<template>
  <div class="maintenance-history">
      <div class="content mt-3">
          <div class="animated fadeIn">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-header">Maintenance History</div>
                          <div class="card-body table-responsive">
                              <div class="col-md-12">
                                  <div class="form-group row view-customer-shedule">
                                      <label for="job_no" class="col-form-label">Job</label>

                                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                                          <v-select  v-model="selected" :on-change="onChange" :options="equipment" label="job_number" id="sale" @search="onSearch"  >
                                          </v-select>
                                      </div>
                                      <button type="button" @click="readHistory" class="btn btn-primary">Retrieve</button>&nbsp;
                                      <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="clearFilter">Reset</button>
                                      <div class="col-sm-2">
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-12" v-if="selectedEquipment">
                                  <div class="form-group row">
                                      <label  class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Model Number</label>
                                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                                          <label v-html="selectedEquipment.model_no" class="col-form-label"></label>
                                      </div>
                                      <label  class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Date of Installation</label>
                                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                                          <label v-html="selectedEquipment.installation_date" class="col-form-label"></label>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group row">
                                      <label  class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Customer Name</label>
                                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                                          <label class="col-form-label" v-html="selectedEquipment.technical_customer.name"></label>
                                      </div>
                                      <label  class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Location</label>
                                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                                          <label v-html="selectedEquipment.location" class="col-form-label"></label>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <table class="table table-bordered">
                                  <thead class="cf">
                                  <tr>
                                      <th scope="col">Year</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Serial No</th>
                                      <th scope="col">job_number</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Service Type</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Invoice No</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Invoice Date</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Payment</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Invoice Value</th>
                                      <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                                  </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                  <template v-for="(equipment) in equipments">
                                      <tbody v-for="(item , index) in equipment.maintenance" >
                                          <tr v-if="first_year == moment(item.due_date).format('YYYY')">
                                              <td>{{index == 0 ? moment(item.due_date).format('YYYY'): '&nbsp;'}}</td>
                                              <td><span>{{equipment.serial_number}}</span></td>
                                              <td><span>{{item.job_number}}</span></td>
                                              <td><span>{{item.due_date}}</span></td>
                                              <td>
                                                  <span v-if="item.type == 1">Repair</span>
                                                  <span v-else-if="item.type == 2">PM</span>
                                                  <span v-else>Upgrade/NFC</span>
                                              </td>
                                              <td>{{item.invoice_no}}</td>
                                              <td>{{item.invoice_date}}</td>
                                              <td>
                                                  <span v-if="item.payment_status == 1">Paid</span>
                                                  <span v-else="">Pending</span>
                                              </td>
                                              <td>{{item.invoice_value}}</td>
                                              <td>
                                                  <router-link onclick="topFunction()" :to="{name:'maintenanceView', params: { id: item.id , equipment: item.equipment_id  }}"
                                                              title="View" class=" btn btn-view" target="_blank">
                                                      <i class="fa fa-eye sky-fa"></i>
                                                  </router-link>
                                              </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr v-else style="border-top: 8px solid #dedede">
                                              <td>{{moment(item.due_date).format('YYYY')}}</td>
                                              <td><span>{{equipment.serial_number}}</span></td>
                                              <td><span>{{item.job_number}}</span></td>
                                              <td><span style="display: none;">{{setFirstYearVariable(item.due_date)}}</span><span>{{item.due_date}}</span></td>
                                              <td>
                                                  <span v-if="item.type == 1">Repair</span>
                                                  <span v-else-if="item.type == 2">PM</span>
                                                  <span v-else>Upgrade/NFC</span>
                                              </td>
                                              <td>{{item.invoice_no}}</td>
                                              <td>{{item.invoice_date}}</td>
                                              <td>
                                                  <span v-if="item.payment_status == 1">Paid</span>
                                                  <span v-else="">Pending</span>
                                              </td>
                                              <td>{{item.invoice_value}}</td>
                                              <td>
                                                  <router-link onclick="topFunction()" :to="{name:'maintenanceView', params: { id: item.id , equipment: item.equipment_id  }}"
                                                              title="View" class=" btn btn-view" target="_blank">
                                                      <i class="fa fa-eye sky-fa"></i>
                                                  </router-link>
                                              </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr v-if="equipment.maintenance.length == 0">
                                              <td colspan="9" class="text-center">
                                                  No Data Found
                                              </td>
                                          </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                  </template>
                              </table>
                              <div class="box-footer clearfix">

                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="loader" v-bind:hidden="loading">
                      <img  :src="'img/loading3.gif'" alt="Loading..." >
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Calling the following method to load data:

```
<script>
import paginationComponent from '../../paginationComponent.vue';
import SpareParts from "./spare_parts.vue";
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            form: new Form({
                equipment_id:'',
            }),
            maintenanceData: {
                current_page: 1
            },
            equipments: [],
            count: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0,
            },
            selectedEquipment:'',
            loading:false,
            serial_number:'',
            selected:'',
            search:'j',
            equipment:[],
            equipment_count:0,
            colorCount:1,
            maintenance_id:'',
            first_year: '',
            loading: true,
        }
    },

   mounted(){
        this.form.equipment_id = this.$route.params.equipment || '';
        this.readHistory()
   },
    components:{
        AmasirSpareParts,
        'pagination-component' : paginationComponent,
    },
    methods:{
       readHistory(){
           this.loading = false;
           this.form.get('technical/maintenance/history-new?equipment='+this.form.equipment_id+'&maintenance='+this.maintenance_id+'&type='+this.search)
               .then(Response => {
                    this.equipments = Response.maintenance;
                    this.loading = true;
                    if (Response.maintenance[0]) {
                        this.first_year = moment(Response.maintenance[0].maintenance[0].due_date).format('YYYY');
                    }
               })
               .catch(Errors => {});
       },

        retrieve(){

        },

        onSearch(search) {
            this.form.fetch('/technical/maintenance/search-history?q='+search+'&type='+this.search+'&equipment='+this.form.equipment_id)
                .then(Response =>{
                    this.equipment = Response.equipment;
                })
                .catch(Errors => {});
        },

        onChange(obj) {
            if(obj !== null){
                if(this.search === 's'){
                    this.form.equipment_id = obj.id;
                    this.selectedEquipment = obj;
                }else{
                    this.maintenance_id = obj.id;
                    this.selectedEquipment = obj.equipment;
                }

                this.selected = obj;

            }else{
                this.selectedEquipment = null;
                this.form.equipment_id = null;
                this.maintenance_id = null;
            }
        },


        firstItem(item, name){
            if(item.length)
            return item[0][name];
        },

        trColor(index){
           let reminder =  (index ) % 3;
           return reminder == 0 ? 'history-color-0' : reminder == 1 ? 'history-color-1' : 'history-color-2';
        },
        dateCal(start, end){
            let starts = moment(start);
            let ends   = moment(end);
            let diff = ends.diff(starts, 'years');
            let year = diff >= 0 ? this.ordinal_suffix_of(diff+1) : '-';
            return year+' year';

        },
        ordinal_suffix_of(i) {
            const j = i % 10, k = i % 100;

            if (j === 1 && k !== 11) {
                return i + "st";
            }
            if (j === 2 && k !== 12) {
                return i + "nd";
            }
            if (j === 3 && k !== 13) {
                return i + "rd";
            }
            return i + "th";
        },

        setFirstYearVariable(date){
            this.first_year = moment(date).format('YYYY');
        },

        moment: function (date) {
            return moment(date);
        },

        clearFilter(){
            window.location.reload();
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Can someone point me out what I did wrong here?

Comment: Can you show your entire component please? Where does readHistory get called from?

Comment: from `mounted()` actually. On page loading. I edited the question @MJ_Wales

Comment: Need to see more of the component, e.g. any watchers or computer props?

Comment: I'll put the code @MJ_Wales. Thanks for your response brother.

Comment: I added all the component @MJ_Wales

Comment: Very difficult to debug because its such a big component. I would recommend refactoring into multiple components first, will help massively with debugging.